# lighttpd service started with root privilege instead of the user set in the server.username

Tags: lighttpd

In my ubuntu box I created a user "lighttpd" and I modified the lighttpd.conf file with the created user, below are the lines modified.

server.username = "lighttpd"
server.groupname = "lighttpd"

I am a root user, and started the lighttpd service by executing with my conf file located in /run folder like below.
/usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /run/lighttpd.conf

On executing the above command, the lighttpd started with root user instead of lighttpd user.

My expectation was the service should start with lighttpd user (which was set server.username = "lighttpd" in conf file).

Answer (score 0):

Run lighttpd with the `-p` flag to print the configuration that lighttpd sees, and then verify that what lighttpd sees matches what you think lighttpd should see.  If lighttpd.conf contains `server.username = "lighttpd"`, then lighttpd will exit with an error if lighttpd can not drop privileges to become user `lighttpd`.

In your case, review the output of: `/usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /run/lighttpd.conf -p`
Then, make sure that any other instance of lighttpd running on your machine has been shut down before you try manually starting lighttpd.  (You can run multiple instances of lighttpd on different ports, but for your experiment, it is simpler to ask you to make sure all other instances of lighttpd have been shut down.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I make sure there is no other lighttpd instance running in my machine, and I tried by executing  "/usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /run/lighttpd.conf -p"  I could able to see server.username = "lighttpd" and server.groupname = "lighttpd" in the configuration printed during lighttpd execution and no error messages printed. But when I execute /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /run/lighttpd.conf " the service started with root but not lighttpd

Comment: Yes, if you execute a program as root, it will start as root.  Does lighttpd then drop privileges to user 'lighttpd' as you have configured `server.username = "lighttpd"` in your lighttpd.conf?  How are you checking who the lighttpd process is running as?  If you have `server.errorlog` in lighttpd.conf, have you looked in there?